# Use trigger for toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<span id="test">​click</span>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

$('#test').toggle(function() {
    alert('true');
}, function() {
    alert('false');
});


$('#test').trigger('click');
```

​

This is working ok, but I would like call the trigger for second the function in toggle - with *alert('false')*. Now, it is always *alert('true')*.

How can I make it? I don't want changed function toggle - only trigger should be changed.

http://jsfiddle.net/xSbTC/

Comment: What do you want exactly? It seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: `$('#test').click().click()`; note that toggle event is deprecated. http://jsfiddle.net/v2TXf/

Comment: Actually, `toggle()` used that way is deprecated, and you should figure out some other way to do what you're trying to do, and there surely are many. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xSbTC/1/) ...

Comment: It's working fine in jsfiddle

Comment: seems to work fine for me.. what exactly you want to do?

Comment: I think the OP wants only the second handler to execute when he calls `.trigger`.

Comment: What do you mean by "trigger second function"? Do you want to set the default state of the toggle, or do you just want to execute the function? Why don't you want to swap the functions?

Comment: i would like execute second function in toggle with trigger - now execute still first function. Ok, if toggle is deprecated what i must use instead toggle? please changed my example. thanks!

Comment: Could you explane what do you need? Do you need execute one function on click event? or you nedd execute two function each other on click event?

Comment: i would like execute with trigger only second function in toggle

Comment: The `toggle` is fine, if the first click occurs then the second time it'll alert `false`.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?  http://jsfiddle.net/xSbTC/4/

Comment: @Archer yes, please add new answer, but i would like use this without additional function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, you're trying to do this without having to repeat the code in the 2nd toggle function.  In order to do this, just move it to a separate function and call that instead...

```
function toggle1() {
    alert("true");
}
function toggle2() {
    alert("false");
}

$('#test').toggle(function() {
    toggle1();
}, function() {
    toggle2();
});

toggle2();
```

​
I've put the code for both parts of toggle into separate functions for clarity.  You could obviously move the code from `toggle1()` into the first toggle function if you wanted to.

http://jsfiddle.net/xSbTC/4/

Answer (score 0):

in order execute only one function you don't need toggle, you can use click

```
$('#test').on('click', function(){alert('false')});​
```