# What to use instead toggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I learned that function toggle() is deprecated. So what can i use instead toggle for this example:

```
<div id="block" style="width: 200px; height: 150px; background-color: blue"></div>

<span id="click">hide</span>
```

​

```
$("#click").toggle(
            function(){
               $("#block").slideUp();
               $(this).html('show');
            },
            function(){
               $("#block").slideDown();
               $(this).html('hide');

            });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2rERJ/

Comment: In this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579288/use-trigger-for-toggle in comments

Comment: using `.toggle()` in THAT way is deprecated.

Comment: ok, sorry! but is similar function to toggle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `click` and `slideToggle` method.

```
$("#click").click(function(){
     var $block = $("#block"),
         $this = $(this);
     $block.slideToggle(function(){
         $this.text($block.is(':visible') ? 'hide' : 'show');
     });
});
```