# What to use instead of `toggle(...)` in jQuery > 1.8?

Tags: toggle, jquery

Now that `toggle(...)` was [deprecated in jQuery 1.8](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-1.8/) and then [**removed** in jQuery 1.9](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed)

What could be used in *general* (aside from using the jQuery migrate script) instead of `toggle(fn, fn2);` thats has the same type of functionality?

Related question (asked about a specific case): [What to use instead toggle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12579667/561731)

---

I **know** that `toggle()` functionality was **not** removed, just the ability to add custom toggle functions (aside from the show/hide default functionality).

Comment: is slideToggle still valid?

Comment: @Lokase I do not see why it would not be?

Comment: Just implement it yourself if you use it often, here are a few examples: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/beginner-function-toggle-deprecated-what-to-use-instead#14737000003769261 I find it much easier to understand if it's hidden behind a function rather than having counter vars all over the place.

Comment: There are a whole bunch of alternative toggles, just use the one that best applies to the animation you are shooting for.

Comment: Curious that the relevant deprecation notes (http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11786) doesn't hint at a suitable replacement. dmethvin's comment (http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11786#comment:7) only alludes to Migrate.

Comment: It's one of those methods where it has a great purpose, but it's named inconveniently. The method was widely used and does save on code, but the .toggle() show hide is used far more, so the former was removed to simplify the api.

Comment: @Lokase: The toggle *event* (http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) has been deprecated; the toggle *effect* (http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) has **not** been deprecated. The ambiguity is part of the reason the event is going/gone away (http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11786#comment:1)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is a simple implementation:

```
$.fn.toggleClick = function() {
    var methods = arguments;    // Store the passed arguments for future reference
    var count = methods.length; // Cache the number of methods 

    // Use return this to maintain jQuery chainability
    // For each element you bind to
    return this.each(function(i, item){
        // Create a local counter for that element
        var index = 0;

        // Bind a click handler to that element
        $(item).on('click', function() {
            // That when called will apply the 'index'th method to that element
            // the index % count means that we constrain our iterator between 0
            // and (count-1)
            return methods[index++ % count].apply(this, arguments);
        });
    });
};
```

and use it as

```
$('selector').toggleClick( function1, function2, ... );
```

Comment: I **like** it. Can you add some comments explaining it all to people? ^_^

Comment: @Neal, made an update because i had forgotten to `return this` to maintain chaining..

Comment: Why do you need the `return` in the click handler?

Comment: @Neal, so that we respect what the user does with their passed methods. For instance if applied to links, the user might do a `return false` at the end, and we want to pass that to our own click handler for use.

Comment: does this work like the old JQuery toggle? I guess my question really is, can I use effects with this function? like old: `toggle('slow', function(){...})`

Comment: @AresDraguna, no. The normal toggle can do that (*if you include jquery UI*). This is an implementation that an older version of jquery had that was doing a completely different thing. It was used to cycle through a list of functions. (*it had nothing to do with toggling an element on screen, see http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/*)