# This codes works in Jquery 1.4.2 but , doesn't work in 1.9.1 , Why? What can i do to use in JQ 1.9.1

Tags: jquery, toggle

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("div").css({
       "width":"80px",
       "height":"40px",
       "margin":"5px",
       "float":"left",
       "background-color":"blue",
       "border":"10px outset",
       "cursor":"pointer"
       });

       $("div").toggle(function(){
          $(this).css({
               "border":"5px inset",
               "background-color":"red"
               });

       },function(){
           $(this).css({
               "border":"10px outset",
               "background-color":"yellow"
               });     
       },function(){
           $(this).css({
               "background-color":"blue"
               });

        });

});
```

Comment: replace .toggle with a click event + flag

Comment: toggle is deprecated in jQuery version 1.9

Comment: jQuery toggle was removed in 1.9.1 http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed The answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911577/jquery-click-toggle-between-two-functions contains a solution.

Answer (score 2):

The `.toggle()` you're using was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in 1.9.

http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

You'll need to replace it with the `.click()` function, or write your own function [simulate  the old functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382857/what-to-use-instead-of-toggle-in-jquery-1-8).

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't very helpful. Post a jsFiddle of what you tried please.