# Jquery toggle ends up hiding the clicked element instead of running functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm pretty new to jquery and i'm pretty stuck with this one. i know it will be something stupid but i have been breaking my head on it for to long.

I want to toggle between the 2 or more functions to animate de specific div's in the site. But i end up making the menu item invisible.

Thanks in advance!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#menu-item-13 a").toggle(
    function () {
        $("#branding").animate({left:416,top:176}).css('z-index', 12);
        $("#a").animate({left:659,top:175});
        $("#post-2").animate({left:160,top:177});
        $("#post-48").animate({left:402,top:324});
        $("nav").animate({left:174,top:56});
        $("#post-30").animate({left:403,top:842});
        $("#post-1").animate({left:902,top:528});
        $("#post-60").animate({left:903,top:55});
        },

    function () {
        $("#branding").animate({left:545,top:176}).css('z-index', 12);
        $("#a").animate({left:84,top:175});
        $("#post-2").animate({left:160,top:85});
        $("#post-48").animate({left:45,top:324});
        $("nav").animate({left:174,top:56});
        $("#post-30").animate({left:403,top:842});
        $("#post-1").animate({left:902,top:528});
        $("#post-60").animate({left:903,top:55});
        });

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This version of toggle(`.toggle(function{}, function(){})`) was [removed in jQuery version 1.9](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed), so if you are using a version > 1.9 then calling toggle will switch the display of the element.

If you want to add back the support for the removed features, you can include the [migration plugin](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-migrate-plugin) as specified in the upgrade notes

Comment: +1 and here is an implementation of the functionality [What to use instead of `toggle(…)` in jQuery > 1.8?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14383246/128165)

Comment: Hey thank you for the information. i tried to fix the problem with a new toggle function but now nothing happens at all. here is the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/Jannikdolferus/futby/

Comment: @user2810940 it should be like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/futby/1/ .. else the methods `een` and `twee` are private to the dom ready callback methods