# jquery toggle triggers display to none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I have some weird behavior. I want to trigger event on click on a `span` tag, let's say `#span` id. When I run this in my console, to test :

```
$('#span').toggle(function(){
    console.log('hi');
},function(){
      console.log('hey');
});
```

The `#span` display is set to none. I tried to find some code which could interfere but I didn't find any...

Comment: You can check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301935/where-has-fn-toggle-handlereventobject-handlereventobject-gone

Answer (score 2):

This version of [toggle was removed](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed) in jQuery 1.9, so if you are using jQuery >= 1.9 it will toggle the display state

One possible solution to enable the removed functionalities is to add the [migration plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382857/what-to-use-instead-of-toggle-in-jquery-1-8/14383246#14383246) after jQuery

Another will be is to write a toggleClick plugin yourself like the below one from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382857/what-to-use-instead-of-toggle-in-jquery-1-8/14383246#14383246)

```
$.fn.toggleClick = function(){
    var methods = arguments, // store the passed arguments for future reference
        count = methods.length; // cache the number of methods 

    //use return this to maintain jQuery chainability
    return this.each(function(i, item){
        // for each element you bind to
        var index = 0; // create a local counter for that element
        $(item).click(function(){ // bind a click handler to that element
            return methods[index++ % count].apply(this,arguments); // that when called will apply the 'index'th method to that element
            // the index % count means that we constrain our iterator between 0 and (count-1)
        });
    });
};
```

then

```
$('#span').toggleClick(function(){
    console.log('hi');
},function(){
      console.log('hey');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Jquery doesn't support `toggle(func,func)` anymore, `toggle()` simply toggles the element `visible` or `invisible`.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/

> .toggle() method signature was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in
>   jQuery 1.9. jQuery also provides an animation method named .toggle()
>   that toggles the visibility of elements. Whether the animation or the
>   event method is fired depends on the set of arguments passed.

http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

you can use [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dnw3g/)

```
function handler1() {
    console.log('hi');
    $(this).one("click", handler2);
}

function handler2() {
    console.log('hey');
    $(this).one("click", handler1);
}
$("#span").one("click", handler1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been deprecated and then removed in `jQuery 1.9`. You'll find some docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/)

Answer (score -1):

There is no more toggle (in that fashion) in jquery 1.9.

What you *can* do is this and make your own toggle-like plugin:

```
$.fn.toggleFn = function(){
    var fns = arguments;
    var fns_length = fns.length;
    var idx = 0;
    this.on('click', function(){
        fns[idx % fns_length].apply(this, arguments);
        idx++;
    });
}
```

Using it:

```
$('#span').toggleFn(function(){
    console.log('hi');
},function(){
      console.log('hey');
});
```