# Create a custom toggle with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have the following code, which fades in HTML via a `.load` into a `.pop-up` modal.

```
$('.about').click(function(){
    $('.pop-up').load('about.php', function(){
        $(this).fadeIn();
    });
```

However, I need a second click to make the `.about` fade out. I understand certain toggle functions are now deprecated. Is there a current method I could use? I have a couple of these functions which will need toggling throughout the code.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/WNJ75/6/

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382857/what-to-use-instead-of-toggle-in-jquery-1-8/14383246#14383246

Comment: toggle method is not deprecated, toggle event is

Comment: Nope.  [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) can be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.about').click(function(){
  $('.pop-up').load('about.php', function(){
    $(this).toggle( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 0):

you can use **[toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)**  but by custom code you can do your customization very well

```
    var toggle=0;
    $('.about').click(function(){
   var $this=$('this');
    if(!toggle)
    {
    $('.pop-up').load('about.php', function(){
            $this.fadeIn();
          toogle=1;
        });
    }
    else{// or do other action which you want
           $this.fadeOut();
        toggle=0;

    }
    });
```