# Why won't this .click() work like .hover()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This works:

```
$("a.hover").hover(function (){
        $(this).css("text-decoration", "underline");
    },function(){
        $(this).css("text-decoration", "none");
    }
);
```

This doesn't:

```
$("a.click").click(function (){
        $(this).css("text-decoration", "underline");
    },function(){
        $(this).css("text-decoration", "none");
    }
);
```

I understand it may not be designed to work like this, but why not?

I'm also not entirely sure what having the second function after the comma actually does. I have only ever written it like this:

```
$("a.click").click(function (){
        $(this).css("text-decoration", "underline");
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/4DygF/7/

Any clarification would be great.

Comment: So you've invented a syntax and then wonder why it doesn't work?

Comment: Trying to understand the logic of it

Comment: handler in/out syntax cannot be used for onclick event

Answer (score 4):

The [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click) register's a click handler to the target set of elements, the [hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover) is a shortcut to register the [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter) and [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave) handlers.

[hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover):

> Bind two handlers to the matched elements, to be executed when the
>   mouse pointer enters and leaves the elements.

[.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click) also had a similar short using [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle) but it was [removed in jQuery 1.9](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed).

For now if you want the same functionality you can look at [this toggleClick() implemetation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382857/what-to-use-instead-of-toggle-in-jquery-1-8/14383246#14383246)

Answer (score 0):

`.hover()` takes two callbacks - one for hovering in and one for hovering out. `.click()` should only be given one callback. Since you're giving it two, it's actually thinking the second one is the click callback.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the jQuery click event, as shown at http://api.jquery.com/click/ is:

```
.click( handler(eventObject) )
```

It takes one parameter, that is the function to execute when the click event has been fired. In your example you provide two functions as parameter to the click function. Therefore this is not going to work.

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is because it also has a second definition, `.click( [eventData ], handler(eventObject) )`. So the second function is actually being used as the handler. Otherwise, it would work fine, JavaScript doesn't mind extra parameters.

Answer (score 0):

for the click you can use if/else like so:
because `Click` event have 1 callback function

```
    var state=0;
    click(function(){
    if(state==0){
    //do this
    state=1;
    }
else{
    //do this
    state=0;
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work by doing something like this:

```
// listen for a.click to be clicked within the scope of the body
$('body').on('click', 'a.click', function(e){

    // prevent the click from registering
    e.preventDefault();

    // check if text-decoration is an underline
    if($(this).css('text-decoration').substring(0, 9) == 'underline'){
        // set it to nothing
        $(this).css('text-decoration', 'none');
    }
    else{
        // set it to underline
        $(this).css('text-decoration', 'underline');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because with [.hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) you can add two handlers (handlerIn, handlerOut), but [.click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) only have one handler

Answer (score 0):

If you want `click` to behave like `toggle`.Try this:

```
var a=1;
$("a.click").click(function (){
if(a==1){
    $(this).css("text-decoration", "underline");
    a=0;
}else{
    $(this).css("text-decoration", "none");
    a=1;
}
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4DygF/9/)