# Simple Mobile jQuery Switch button & alternative to .toggle latest jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a simple jQuery switch button. The kind you mostly see on mobile.

**[ on | off ]**

I have the below snippet that I found in a jsfiddle. But it won't work; I tried wrapping it in -

```
$('.slider-button').toggle(function(){
    $(this).addClass('on').html('Quizz');
    },function(){
    $(this).removeClass('on').html('Read');
    });
})
```

I tried wrapping it in a on ready as well.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.slider-button').toggle(function(){
    $(this).addClass('on').html('Quizz');
    },function(){
    $(this).removeClass('on').html('Read');
    });
})
```

I'm loading the latest in jQuery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
```

Mark-Up:

```
<div class="slider-frame">
    <span class="slider-button">OFF</span>
</div>
```

It simply wont toggle onClick.

Edit: Here's an attempt at a fiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/Hn27Q/

Still can't get it; and actually none of the CSS3 is being seen at mobile; any suggestions appreciated.

- Bill

Comment: Do u have the appropriate css files? Compare runtime applied css from working sample and ur attempt. Srry im mobile.

Comment: what exactly doesn't work? The code you posted seems to be alright. Can you provide a fiddle reproducing your problem?

Comment: toggle() was removed in 1.9. Please see the docs.

Comment: Man, that could be it; I'm load the latest 2 in jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.toggle` version that accepted functions to alternate on clicks has been removed as of v1.9 (*see http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/*)

You can see [What to use instead of `toggle(...)` in jQuery > 1.8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382857/what-to-use-instead-of-toggle-in-jquery-1-8/14383246#14383246) for an implementation of that functionality as an extension..

You should use it like this

```
$('.slider-button').toggleClick (function(){
        $(this).addClass('on').html('Quizz');
    },function(){
        $(this).removeClass('on').html('Read');
    });
});
```

---

for ease of use i copy the code here

```
$.fn.toggleClick = function(){
    var methods = arguments, // store the passed arguments for future reference
        count = methods.length; // cache the number of methods 

    //use return this to maintain jQuery chainability
    return this.each(function(i, item){
        // for each element you bind to
        var index = 0; // create a local counter for that element
        $(item).click(function(){ // bind a click handler to that element
            return methods[index++ % count].apply(this,arguments); // that when called will apply the 'index'th method to that element
            // the index % count means that we constrain our iterator between 0 and (count-1)
        });
    });
};
```