# Replacement for .toggle( in jQuery 1.9

Tags: jquery, click, toggle

I found different alternatives to toggle here for jQuery 1.9, but I don't get it to work im my case here:

```
$('.thumb.flip').toggle(
function () {
$(this).find('.thumb-wrapper').addClass('flipStop');
},
function () {
$(this).find('.thumb-wrapper').removeClass('flipStop flipIt');
}
);
```

Comment: if you want the same code work have a look at the migration project, else use an alternate like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382857/what-to-use-instead-of-toggle-in-jquery-1-8/14383246#14383246

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass Your code as-is seems to have a logic problem, or something's missing... What is the significance of `flipIt`? you never added it to begin with, so why would it be there anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give .flip a data-attribute

```
<div class="thumb flip" data-clicked="0">

$('.thumb.flip').click(function () {
    var data = $(this).data('clicked'), $descendant=$(this).find('.thumb-wrapper');
    if (data) {
        $descendant.removeClass('flipStop flipIt');
    } else {
        $descendant.addClass('flipStop');
    }
    data == 0 ? $(this).data('clicked', 1) : $(this).data('clicked', 0);
});
```

Or you can use elseif

```
$('.thumb.flip').click(function () {
    if ($(this).find('.thumb-wrapper').hasClass('flipstop')) {
        $(this).find('.thumb-wrapper').removeClass('flipStop flipIt');
    } else {
        $(this).find('.thumb-wrapper').addClass('flipStop');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "click" event and then check using ":visible" (if the element is visible at the moment):

- if the element is visible - hide it by adding a class like your code or just: ~.hide()
- if the element isn't visible - add/remove class or use: ~.show()