# jquery old toggle alternative since 1.9

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#open').toggle(
        function(){
        $('#login form').slideDown(300);
        $(this).addClass('close');
    },
        function(){
            $('#login form').slideUp(300);
            $(this).removeClass('close');
    });
});
</script>

<div id="login">
        <p id="open">Login</p>
        <form>
            <p>
                <label for="username">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="password">Password: </label>
                <input type="text" name="password" id="password">
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" >
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
```

With the new versions of jQuery. What could be an alternative way of achieving this same behavior?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use [click()](http://api.jquery.com/click) handler along with [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) and [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#open').click(function () {
        $('#login form').slideToggle(300);
        $(this).toggleClass('close');
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LZ7tU/)

But if you are looking for a general replacement, you can have a look at the different toggleClick() methods like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382857/what-to-use-instead-of-toggle-in-jquery-1-8/14383246#14383246)

Answer (score 0):

What you could do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var clicks = 0;
    $(element).event(function(){
        clicks++;
        if (clicks % 2) {
            //Some stuff to do if odd
        } else {
            //Some stuff to do if even
        }
    });
});
```