# jQuery Uncaught TypeError but works on different page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm getting the following error message in my console:
[image]

This is from this webpage: http://mylzh.net/isaacBingo.php?seed=2jrxjc

However on the original page it works: http://mylzh.net/bingo/bindingofisaac/index.html?seed=2jrxjc

Comment: do you have a script like `$(this).addClass("redsquare").removeClass("greensquare");` anywere

Comment: we need to see the context of this code. where does that function definition appear? I'm not sure `this` will be the value you expect it to be either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the following code

```
$("#bingo tr td:not(.bingo_select), #selected td").toggle(function () {
    $(this).addClass("greensquare");
}, function () {
    $(this).addClass("redsquare").removeClass("greensquare");
}, function () {
    $(this).removeClass("redsquare");
});
```

This version of [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) was removed in [jQuery 1.9](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed).

While executing this code jQuery assumes it to be the version that takes 3 params like [.toggle( duration [, easing ] [, complete ] )](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-duration-easing-complete), so it considers the second argument(a function) as `easing` value and uses it internally like

```
return this.pos = b = this.options.duration ? o.easing[this.easing](a, this.options.duration * a, 0, 1, this.options.duration) : a, this.now = (this.end - this.start) * b + this.start, this.options.step && this.options.step.call(this.elem, this.now, this), c && c.set ? c.set(this) : Kb.propHooks._default.set(this), this
```

As a solution look at the [toggleClick()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382857/what-to-use-instead-of-toggle-in-jquery-1-8/14383246#14383246) plugin