# jQuery click(function) not working

Tags: jquery, slidedown

I'm trying to create a clickable sub-menu with `slideDown()` via jQuery.
However - `hover()` is working as intended, but `click()` doesn't do anything.

Here's my jQuery:

```
$("#n_ulist li").click(function(){
    $("ul", this).stop().slideDown(500);
    },
    function() {
    $("ul", this).stop().slideUp(500);  
});
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: [.click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) doesn't allow two functions - are you thinking of [.hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Comment: and how am I supposed to slideUp the dropdown when clicking another list element? - sorry I'm new to this :(

Comment: You would need to add something like `$(this).parent().find('ul').stop().slideUp(500);` in the same click function (before your slideDown) - or if your menu is more than one level `$('#n_ulist').find('ul').stop().slideUp(500);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following instead:

```
$("#n_ulist li").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('ul').stop().slideUp(500);
    $("ul", this).stop().slideDown(500);
});
```

or if your menu is more than one level you may need to use

```
$('#n_ulist').find('ul').stop().slideUp(500);
```

**EDIT**

As per your comments

```
$("#n_ulist li").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('ul').stop().slideUp(500);
    $("ul", this).stop().slideToggle(500).click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: that worked fine, thanks ;)
but is there a way to accomplish the same effect when I click on the parent element again to close(`slideUp()`) the submenu?
So I want to slide-up the submenu when I click on the same element and when I click another parent element...

Comment: change the `slideDown` to `slideToggle`

Comment: well I got a problem now - if I click any object in the submenu, the list slides up too...that is not intended...any ideas?

Comment: see edit above - you need to stop the event propagating when you click on the child

Answer (score 0):

The [click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) function takes only one callback as its argument, so always your first callback `slideDown(500);` gets executed....

You can use [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)

```
$("#n_ulist li").click(function () {
    $("ul", this).stop().slideToggle(500);
});
```

The [hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) takes 2 callbacks as arguments, 1 for [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and another for [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/). There were a [toggle()](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed) version which was doing the same for click event but it was removed in jQuery 1.9.

If you want a plugin which will allow you to do the same look at this [toggleClick()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382857/what-to-use-instead-of-toggle-in-jquery-1-8/14383246#14383246) implementation.

Comment: thanks mate, is there a way to toggle the slideUp when clicking on another list element?

Answer (score 0):

May be by using [.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) .