# jQuery newest library do not work script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this [script](http://jsfiddle.net/zA23k/215/) (more/less text). When I implemented to code with jQuery lib 1.11, he does not work. I can not know why?

Code:

```
<span class="teaser">text goes here</span>
<span class="complete"> this is the complete text being shown</span>
<span class="more">more...</span>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".more").toggle(function(){
  $(this).text("less..").siblings(".complete").show();    
}, function(){
  $(this).text("more..").siblings(".complete").hide();    
});
```

Can ask for help? Thanks

Comment: Are there any errors in your browser's JavaScript console? What does "not work?" Mean, specifically? Oh, and [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) was removed in jQuery 1.9; so there *should* be errors.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14383246/128165 for an implementation of the deprecated `toggle` method.

Answer (score 2):

[`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) is used on the elements you want to show and hide, rather than being an event that happens.  You probably want to bind to [the `click` event](http://api.jquery.com/click/) of `more`:

```
$(".more").click(function(){
  if ($(this).siblings(".complete").is(":visible"))
      $(this).text("more..").siblings(".complete").hide();    
  else
      $(this).text("less..").siblings(".complete").show();    
});
```

The [`toggle` event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in 1.9.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/szzot94c/1/)

Comment: Note that your fiddle works as it's referencing jQuery 1.5.2.