# unable to access elment after append

Tags: jquery

I'm using append to add an image to a `<p id="p10">`

```
$('#p10').append("<img src='plus.png' id='clicker' />");
```

I want to reference the image I've added via the append with the toggle:

```
$('#clicker').toggle(function() {
        // toggle code here
}, function() {
    // toggle code here
});
```

I cannot access the image element via the id to use the toggle. If I comment out the toggle, the image shows up on the page. As soon as I add the toggle code, the image blinks for a second and then disappears.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: toggle an image on and off

Comment: @Dman100, is the toggle happening on click or other event?

Comment: When or which event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the version of `.toggle` that accepts function arguments that should execute serially has been removed. (*[deprecated since v1.8, removed since 1.9](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)*)

`.toggle` only shows/hides an element now. So calling the `.toggle` on the clicker just hides it.

For an alternative implementation see [What to use instead of `toggle(...)` in jQuery > 1.8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382857/what-to-use-instead-of-toggle-in-jquery-1-8/14383246#14383246)

Answer (score 0):

```
var imgTag = "<img>";
    imgTag.attr('src','plus.png');
    imgTag.attr('id','clicker');
    $('#p10').append(imgTag);

    $(imgTag).toggle(function() {
            // toggle code here
    }, function() {
        // toggle code here
    });
```