# what to use instead of .toggle() method in jQuery-1.9.1 or later

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

See my code below

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    creatersdropdown();

    var $dropTrigger = $(".rsdropdown dt a");
    var $languageList = $(".rsdropdown dd ul");

    // open and close list when button is clicked
    $dropTrigger.toggle(function() {
        $languageList.slideDown(200);
        $dropTrigger.addClass("active");
    }, function() {
        $languageList.slideUp(200);
        $(this).removeAttr("class");
    });

});
```

**.toggle()** is not working with jQuery-1.9.1 or later, so what is the instead of **.toggle()** method?

how to write the code above without using **.toggle()** in jQuery-1.9.1 or later?

Comment: Possible duplication is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579667/what-to-use-instead-toggle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `.is('visible')` jquery method. and do as you wish
in your case it would be something like :

```
$("#someButton").click(function () {
    if ($dropTrigger.is('visible')) {
            $languageList.slideUp(200);
            $(this).removeAttr("class");
        }else {
            $languageList.slideDown(200);
            $dropTrigger.addClass("active");

        }
    });
```

Comment: yahh, i got it, but in my project it is not working, see  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Rousnay/dEp5Y)  here i am using jQuery-1.8.3, but how to make it working with jQuery-1.9.1 or later?

Comment: updated your link, works ok now... dont forget to accept my answer :)

Comment: could you please give me the update link of "jsfiddle"?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dEp5Y/5/